# RHEL 5.x SCSI Driver .img update for initrd.img

Tags: rhel5, drivers

I have production DB server (RHEL 5.1) with LSI Megaraid driver loaded during setup via DUD (Driver Upd Diskett).

Now I'd like to update kernel and other packeges to 5.4 version. I also downloaded new LSI SCSI driver (megasr-13.11.0922.2009-1-rhel50-u4-all.img ).
Could you explain the necessary steps to make this driver visible on boot for new kernel (lets assume, that I've already update kernel to 5.4)?

I read the article on [Redhat](http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-17783) - "How do I add a driver to the initrd.img". Does it contain all the steps I need?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an enterprise server (Rack-mounted, pre-built?) – if so then your hardware vendor should provide a package containing the right drivers you need (Dell provide RPM packages, as do HP).

Whenever I've used an LSI card with RHEL5 before, it's worked without the particular drivers, just with whatever's in the kernel. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the driver update disk - that's only for when you are initially installing the OS.

LSI should have some drivers available for download - either RPM or tarballs.

Comment: Didnt find rpm or tarballs anyway ((( I'll try to grab drivers from .img